# Ubuntu 17.04, freezes intermittently with nvidia 340.102

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 17.04

I am using an old Lenovo Y530 laptop which comes with the following card

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98M [GeForce 9300M GS] (rev a1)
```

I freshly installed 17.04, after which I am facing a weird issue where the graphical interface (basically the screen) freezes, the mouse movement is still registered, but no action is reflected back.
TTL switching doesn't work. No keyboard action is registered. Only hard reboot through power button works.

This is when install the suggested 340.102 driver from available Proprietary Drivers. When I Revert to nouveau drivers I do not face this problem.

This is not a huge issue but an inconvenience that I don't want.

Comment: Old Nvidia drivers are not good. Use nouveau then. Old cards are poorly supported by proprietary drives. Sometimes they work, sometimes don't. And I see no reason of using 17.04 on this old laptop. It will be EoL soon. Why not install an LTS?

Comment: @Pilot6 well, the laptop is old, but is my daily driver. I upgraded to 17.04 from 16.10, and faced a few issues, post which i did a fresh installation.  I guess I need to downgrade to 16.04LTS

Answer (score 0):

Switch to noveau and then login not using software rendering
also disable hardware acceleration in google chrome.